# Routing by item id using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to read from an API a product to display. Then when I press on one of the displayed products it should route me to a component for details about this product using the product ID in the url and product details to view on the page. 
I read the data from the API here and displayed the products with details.

```
class Tshirts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://pwathemes.com/demo-api/wp-json/pwacommercepro/products')
      .then(results => results.json()).then((products) => {
        console.log(products);
        this.setState({ products });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.products.map(item => ({
      id: item.id,
      header: item.name,
      description: item.price + '$',
      image: item.images[0],

    }));

    return (
      <div>
        <Bar head="T-Shirts" />
        <Dropdown text="SORT BY COST" fluid selection options={sortOptions} className="dropp" />
        <Header as="h4" textAlign="center" attached className="hh4" >{list.length} ITEMS </Header>
        <Link to="/tdetailed/:id">
          <Card.Group items={list} itemsPerRow={2} />
        </Link>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to add a link to route by product ID. How can I send the details as props for the other component ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is link the entire group of objects to one specific object.

Instead you should put the Link component inside of the Card.Group and use the id of the desired product when you map over the objects in items. I'm guessing that you want to link to that product that was clicked, in that case wrap the element of that product card with a

`<Link to={'*pathname/*' + id }> <YourProductCardComponentOrButtonElement /> </Link>`

"/tdetailed/:id" (this should be only in your routing component to specify that it's an id that is part of the exact route)

Comment: The thing is that Card.Group is a library in react-semantic-ui

Comment: You should probably label this with react-semantic-ui as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to send the product props that the listing component has to the detail component on the `/tdetailed/:id` route, right?

Don't do this - it's an anti-pattern. You're making the two routes too closely coupled. Consider the following scenario: a user arrives to your site following a deep link directly to a product detail, say `/tdetailed/123`. Under these conditions the user never visited the listing page, never downloaded the list from the API, so the data for product `123` doesn't exist in your app.

The solution is for every route to be entirely responsible for loading the data it needs from scratch. So the component rendering the `/tdetailed/:id` route needs to fetch data for the product itself, in `componentDidMount`. It gathers the correct `id` to use from the url, via the props React Router provides.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Link/>` attribute also accepts an object. You can convert your route to an object like -

```
let data = {pathname: '/tdetailed/:id', customKey: 'CustomValue' }
```

So, whatever your component routes to, this whole object will be provided to it in the `location` object. So, all you need to do is

```
<Link to={data}>...</Link>
```

and fetch it in the routed component as -

```
this.props.location.customKey
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for this ! But I didn't get the part how do I link each product with his own data. The other component is only details about the selected product

Comment: pass down route id as a prop as well? and fetch them in your component?